# SAP Business Object Performance Issue with Impala

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala, business-objects

We are switching from Oracle to Hadoop due to slow performance with Oracle DB, built a universe with Cloudera Simba ODBC connections scheduled a report expecting a faster performance compare to Oracle DB but the report took more than 2 hours, took the same query and ran in HUE SQL editor the result got back in less than 2 mins

We tested in DEV, TEST, & PROD, & also tried switching to JDBC connection no difference, we feel its the network's latency issue and opened a Case with SAP

Point to note here that our Hadoop servers and BO servers are in two different locations NCAL and SCAL, we have 3.5 million records to pull

I am looking for some tested advice here on this issue if anyone has already faced such issue

Comment: Are you sure you connected to Impala and not the HiveServer, and actually ran a MapReduce job?

Comment: It is connected to Impala server. Not sure about what is MapReduce job?

Comment: Are you asking "what is MapReduce", or "what job is running internally by your query"? If you had connected to port 10000, which is HiveServer2, for a Cloudera CDH cluster, the default execution engine for Hive is MapReduce.

Comment: "servers are in two different locations" ... Could certainly be network latency in that case. Hue is local to the Hadoop cluster. Perhaps you should setup monitoring on the network traffic, if possible